# ifelse statements with multiple conditions and NA

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to create a column "complete" based on logical statements for values of one other column. The column is named "etc001_processed" and includes the numbers of testlets one person completed. There are a lot of people who didn't complete the "etc001" testlet at all, so there are a lot of NA's. I want the create the column "complete" which:

1. is NA if etc001_processed is NA
2. is 1 if etc001_processed is 12
3. is 0 if etc001_processed is not 12 or NA

```
> print(dat_de$etc001_processed)
 [1] NA NA NA NA 12 NA NA NA NA NA NA 12 NA  9 NA 12  7 NA 12 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 12 12 NA NA NA 12 NA NA NA NA
[44] 12 12 NA 12 NA 12 NA NA 12 12 NA 12 NA 12 NA NA 12
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it via nested `ifelse` or `case_when` from `dplyr` specifying each condition separately but in this case you can directly do

```
dat_de$complete <- as.integer(dat_de$etc001_processed == 12)
dat_de

#   temp etc001_processed complete
#1     1               NA       NA
#2     2               NA       NA
#3     3               NA       NA
#4     4               NA       NA
#5     5               12        1
#6     6               NA       NA
#7     7               NA       NA
#8     8               NA       NA
#9     9               NA       NA
#10   10               NA       NA
#11   11               12        1
#12   12               NA       NA
#13   13                9        0
#14   14               NA       NA
#15   15               12        1
#16   16                7        0
```

**data**

```
dat_de <- data.frame(temp = 1:16, etc001_processed =  c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 12, 
                     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,12, NA,  9 ,NA, 12,  7))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `if-else` statement, I would like to recommend `ifelse()`, i.e.,

```
df <- within(df, complete <- ifelse(etc001_processed==12,1,
                                    ifelse(is.na(etc001_processed),NA,0)))
```

**Example with dummy data**

```
df <- data.frame(etc001_processed =  c(NA, 3, NA, NA, 12, NA, 5, NA, 6, NA,12, NA,  8 ,9, NA,  1))

df <- within(df, complete <- ifelse(etc001_processed==12,1,
                                    ifelse(is.na(etc001_processed),NA,0)))
```

which gives

```
> df
   etc001_processed complete
1                NA       NA
2                 3        0
3                NA       NA
4                NA       NA
5                12        1
6                NA       NA
7                 5        0
8                NA       NA
9                 6        0
10               NA       NA
11               12        1
12               NA       NA
13                8        0
14                9        0
15               NA       NA
16                1        0
```